# Use R to do web Crawler and it can not capture content I need(text mining)(Taiwanese BBS, ptt)

Tags: r, text, text-mining

this is Joe from National Taipei University of Business, Taiwan. I'm  currently doing a research on online games and E-sports by text mining in the social media. I chose to get the data from the most popular BBS, "PTT",in Taiwan, but it seems my code can only capture the article titles but cannot reach the contents.

I tried to get the texts from www.ptt.cc/bbs/LoL/index6402.html to index6391, and the code I used is here in [my R code data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wde1dejrqcssv0j/R_try.R?dl=0) or [R code txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5p7ixjhepp68ow/try.txt?dl=0) or following.

```
install.packages("httr")
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages("xml2")

library(httr)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(xml2)


data <- list()

for( i in 6391:6402) {
  tmp <- paste(i, '.html', sep='')
  url <- paste('https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/LoL/index', tmp, sep='')
  tmp <- read_html(url)
  html <- htmlParse(getURL(url))
  url.list <- xml_find_all(tmp, "//div[@class='title']/a[@href]")
  data <- rbind(data, as.matrix(paste('https://www.ptt.cc', url.list, sep='')))
}
data <- unlist(data)

getdoc <- function(line){
  start <- regexpr('https://www', line)[1]
  end <- regexpr('html', line)[1]

  if(start != -1 & end != -1){
    url <- substr(line, start, end+3)
    html <- htmlParse(getURL(url), encoding='UTF-8')
    doc <- xpathSApply(html, "//div[@id='main-content']", xmlValue)
    name <- strsplit(url, '/')[[1]][4]
    write(doc, gsub('html', 'txt', name))
  }      
}
setwd("E:/data")
sapply(data, getdoc)
```

But this code can only capture the titles and my txt files are empty. I'm not sure which part goes wrong and thus I need some advice from you at stackoverflow.

Any advice will be very much appreciated and anyone helping me with this will be on the list of acknowledgement in my thesis, and, if you're curious about it, I will inform you of the research result after it is done. :)

Comment: welcome to SO. you rly need to post a minimal reproducible example that illustrates what you're trying to do and why it isn't working. linking to code on Dropbox (et al) is sketchy and makes it hard for others to learn from solutions on this site.

Comment: I am a SO rookie, thank you for tour advice, I modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

# change the end number
pages <- map(6391:6392, ~read_html(sprintf("https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/LoL/index%d.html", .)))

map(pages, ~xml_find_all(., "//div[@class='title']/a[@href]")) %>% 
  map(xml_attr, "href") %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    URL <- sprintf("https://www.ptt.cc%s", x)
    pg <- read_html(URL)
    data_frame(
      url=URL,
      text=html_nodes(pg, xpath="//div[@id='main-content']") %>% html_text()
    )
  }) -> df

glimpse(df)
## Observations: 40
## Variables: 2
## $ url  <chr> "https://www.ptt.cc/bbs/LoL/M.1481947445.A.17B.html", "https://www.ptt.cc/b...
## $ text <chr> "作者rainnawind看板LoL標題[公告] LoL 板 開始舉辦樂透!時間Sat Dec 17 12:04:03 2016\nIMT KDM 勝...
```

to make a data frame or sub out the last part with:

```
dir.create("pttdocs")

map(pages, ~xml_find_all(., "//div[@class='title']/a[@href]")) %>% 
  map(xml_attr, "href") %>% 
  flatten_chr() %>% 
  walk(function(x) {

    URL <- sprintf("https://www.ptt.cc%s", x)

    basename(x) %>% 
      tools::file_path_sans_ext() %>% 
      sprintf(fmt="%s.txt") %>% 
      file.path("pttdocs", .) -> fil

    pg <- read_html(URL)

    html_nodes(pg, xpath="//div[@id='main-content']") %>% 
      html_text() %>% 
      writeLines(fil)

  })
```

to write files to a directory.

Comment: I am really grateful for your answer

Comment: I try 
write.table(df,"filename.txt",sep="\t",row.names=FALSE)
but I want to save every content....